# Evaluate integral over area

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Evaluate integral function:
$$ f(x,y) = (1+x+y)^{-2}$$

and area:
$$x=2y, y = 2x, x+y=6$$

Do I need a change of variable?

Comment: There is no integral here. Is it a volume?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here's a picture of the bounds of the integration. Note that the function is constant over any line of the form $x+y=c$, so we can rotate the region by $45^\circ$ to get the region in the next picture

[image]

The region defined by the lines $$3y=x,\;-3y=x,\;x=3\sqrt2$$And hence, the integral is

$$2\int\limits_0^{3\sqrt2}\frac u3\cdot\bigg(\frac1{1+u}\bigg)^2du$$
This should be quite easy to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

You could integrate without changing variables,  first the area between the bounds $y=x/2$ and $y=2x$ over $x\in(0,2)$, and then the area between the bounds $y=x/2$ and $y=6-x$ over $x\in(2,4)$,

$$I= \int_0^2dx \int_{x/2}^{2x}\frac{dy}{(1+x+y)^2}+  \int_2^4dx \int_{x/2}^{6-x}\frac{dy}{(1+x+y)^2}$$

$$=\int_0^2 \left( -\frac1{1+3x}+\frac2{2+3x}\right)dx +
\int_2^4 \left( -\frac17+\frac2{2+3x}\right)dx$$

$$=\left[  -\frac13\ln(1+3x)+\frac23 \ln(2+3x)  \right]_0^2+
\left[  -\frac x7+\frac23 \ln(2+3x)  \right]_2^4$$
$$=-\frac27+\frac13\ln 7$$